# Genexus Extensions SDK - How to develop extensions for Genexus Server?

Tags: sdk, genexus

I'm trying to develop .NET Framework Extensions for Genexus Server to listen to basic events like:

- Lock Events
- Commit Events
- Update Events

**EDIT**

I have tried pasting packages that derives from `AbstractPackage` and implements `IGxPackageBL` from Genexus SDK inside `GXServerInstance/VDir/BinGenexus/Packages` folder and listen to `LockEvents` using the `EventSubscription` with `ServerEvents.BeforeLockObject` but the package doesn't seen to be initialized with Genexus Server. This Class comes from `Genexus.Server.Common.ddl`.

Here is what I tried so far:

I created the project from the "Genexus Package Visual Studio Template":

[image]

`Package.cs`

[image]

`AssemblyInfo.cs`

[image]

The Extension doesn't seen to be loaded, here is what the `https://mygxserver/v16/extensions.aspx` shows:

[image]

The `GXServer.log` file doesn't seen to be logging any errors, and shows that the extension was actually loaded, despite not working...

[image]

- How can I setup an extension for Genexus Server (16)?
- What DLLs From the server can I use to implement functionalities to my extension?

Answer (score 1):

GeneXus Server extensions are developed the same way as GeneXus extensions, and have to be installed in the path that you mentioned. The distinction here is that GXserver only loads **BL extensions**.

You can classify extensions in two ways:

1. **UI extensions:** These extensions are loaded only in GeneXus IDE, and can add user interface components, such as tool windows, toolbars, menus, commands, editors, etc.
2. **BL extensions:** These extensions are loaded whenever the business logic layer is loaded. This is, besides when running GeneXus IDE, it also includes when running MSBuild tasks, or when GXserver service is loaded.
   These kind of extensions commonly:

   - Add new object types
   - Add new parts to objects
   - Add new properties to objects
   - Implement services defined in SDK or other shared assemblies

In order for an extension to be considered a BL extension, it must comply with the following:

1. The `Package` class must extend `AbstractPackage` and implement `IGxPackageBL`. eg:

   ```cs
   public class Package : AbstractPackage, IGxPackageBL
   ```

   I noticed in the image provided, that the implementation of `IGxPackageBL` is missing. This interface doesn't define any new members to the package beside those already inherited from `AbstractPackage`, but the package loader checks for it anyway.
2. Inform in the `PackageAttribute` that the package is NOT a UI extension. eg:

   ```cs
   [assembly : PackageAttribute(typeof(Package), IsUIPackage = false)]
   ```

After making these changes, and copying the package assembly inside the `VDir\BinGenexus\Package` folder, you can navigate to the extensions page (eg: https://mygxserver/v16/extensions.aspx) in your browser, and you should see your extension loaded.

As for the binaries you can use, the GXserver SDK is a work in progress. In v17 we started distributing a new folder with the SDK named `BinServer` which includes the binaries we are comfortable making part of the SDK, which at the moment contians `Genexus.Server.Common.dll` and `GeneXus.Server.ExternalTool.dll`.

Comment: I edited the question with everything that I used, even when implementing  `IGxPackageBL` and setting `ÌsUIPackage = false` the extension does not load...

Comment: Try turning on [GXserver log](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?10948,Tracing+GeneXus+Server). In the log file, you should see when the server loads, messages like `GeneXusServer - Scanning package 'YourPackageAssembly.dll'` followed by `GeneXusServer - Package 'YourPackageAssembly.dll'`.
Downwards you'll find more tracing messages related to your package loading, such as `Initialize`, `Loading categories`, and more. Check if you find something odd over there.

Comment: I've edited the question with the `GXServer.log` file content, apparently it says the extension was loaded succesfully, despite not executing the beforeLock events and neither showing in the dashboard page.
There are no errors/warnings in the Log File...

Comment: @Bruno.S I'm sorry I hadn't seen your comment before. Were you able to sort this out?
I'd suggest checking first that you find the messages `Initialize`, `Loading categories` and more, related to your own extension. If you see those, try overriding `PostInitialize` method in the package class, and add a trace there using the `TraceManager` class.
Just to be safe, whenever you override any method in the package class, keep an invocation to the base method in your override, just in case.